# How to sort posts by votes for a specific date range with NoSQL?

Tags: database, nosql

I'm currently trying to get my head around NoSQL (which is kinda hard coming from SQL). Since I'd like to go through some examples to get a better understanding I'm currently a bit stuck with the following:

Assuming I've got the following collections: user, posts and votes. A user can up or downvote posts and filter them. How do I need to structure my collections for efficiently query something like "most upvoted posts within the last 24h"?

My first guess would be something like:

```
votes:
  user (user id)
  post (post id)
  value (down or upvote)

posts:
  title
  votes:
    user (user id)
    date
    value (down or upvote)
```

What immediately caught my attention on this approach is: I'd need to update votes within votes and posts everytime a user changes his vote, right? Other than that that'd be my solution for this problem, since I can access the votes date on every post. My only other concern at this point would be that this *maybe* can be problematic with thousands of votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a perfect world, you could just keep a count on the post. Upvotes would increment it, downvotes would decrement it. (There are atomic operations just for this case.) This means every "show me a post (with votes) takes one tiny read. Unfortunately, that doesn't prevent users from duplicate voting.

​

So use 2 tables: one for the Posts, and one for the users.

When a user votes, you store their vote in the users table. That table stores UID + POSTID (primary keys) and also stores their VOTE. You can use [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) streams to trigger a Lambda function that "copies" the up/down vote onto the Post. Every per-user upvote is stored on users first, where is de-dupped, and only rolled up onto the actual Post if it's a valid change in the user vote.

​

This means every "show me a post (with votes) takes one tiny read, and "user vote" is two simple writes.